# Find conf file regardless how application started

Tags: java, relative-path

I'm newbie to java.

I have some directory structure

```
  product/
        conf/
        classes/com/../..
```

`conf/` contains some configuration file, while under `classes/` I have my application.

How can I ensure from inside java code that I'm able to find file in `conf/` despite way I'm executing it (e.g. from eclipse, from different directories, from crontab etc.).

**P.S.**

Files in `conf/` are not resources, since required to be edited by user. 
Is there're way to know where my `.class`, so I canuse relative path form that directory to reach my directory (e.g. MY_CLASS_DIR/../../../../conf)

Comment: @dimba: Do the configuration files change at any time after deployment?  Does the program need to update them, or just read them?

Comment: System.getProperty("user.dir"));

Comment: user.dir will return the current directory, not an absolute path. Ah - now I see the headline, which asks more or less the opposite of the message body. The CWD is always changing (eclipse, crontab, different dirs), not constant. The body seems to ask for a never changing directory.

Comment: @user Title is incorrect, I've change it. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @dimba: "Just to read them" In that case I recommend the [answer by dacwe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121074/find-conf-file-regardless-how-application-started/6121312#6121312).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the absolute path, including the way to product.

Or you may use a configuration setting, by starting your program like

```
java -DXY_HOME=/some/path/product ...
```

From the javacode, you use it:

```
String xyHome = System.getProperty ("XY_HOME")
```

Or you use a kind of inifile in your home directory, where you specify where to look for the conf-directory.

Rereading your question multiple times, it is unclear to me what your goal is. To find the conf dir independently from where you are (eclipse, crontab, ...)? But the headline asks for the CWD, which is the opposite - the directory, depending on where you are.

Both is possible, but you have to decide what you want.

Comment: I've change title of the question to remove ubiquity.

Comment: @What -Dconfdir gives? How Can I refer to it from app?

Comment: The -D switch is meant to pass a configuration. It can be whatever you want - a string, a number, an URL or IP, a directory. `java -help` reveals `-D<name>=<value> set a system property`. For a single system installation, you could use a fixed path, known to the application, fixed in the sources. To make the whole thing moveable, a property, at best the root of your directory structure, namely `product` could be specified as a system property and in this way you can handle different conf- or instal-dirs (usersettings, versions), as well as adaption to foreign machines. (See above for code).

Comment: Accepted - -D gives me to use conf/ while its not a resource

Answer (score 3):

I would put the conf directory into the class path. That way you can always find them by:

```
YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("conf/....");
```

Comment: +1 Especially since the OP only needs *read access* to the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Its safe to use relative paths than absolute paths. Even if you JAR your classes tomorrow it will work as is,

Put you configuration files in classpath during deployment.(Please note that
project directory structure can be different from that of deployment directory structure)

```
product/       
    classes/com/../..
    classes/conf/some_conf.properties
```

Then you can use Apache common configuration to get the URL of file

```
URL urlOfFile = org.apache.commons.configuration.
ConfigurationUtils.locate("conf/some_conf.properties");
```

The other alternative you can try is,

```
URL urlOfFile = <SomeClassFromClassesFolder>.class.
getClassLoader().getResource(resourceFile);
```

Once you get the URL of your configuration file getting stream out of it very simple,

```
InputStream stream = urlOfFile.openStream();
```

Good luck.

For you understanding you can refer the following as well,

http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/showTutorials.action?tutorialId=Java_IO_CurrentWorkingDirectory

http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/showTutorials.action?tutorialId=Java_Reflection_WheretheClassloadedfrom
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can find out what is the absolute path of the working dir by:

```
String str = new File("").getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: If I run "java -cp a/b/c" from directory /A/B/C will it return me /A/B/C or a/b/c?

Comment: new File ("") will display the current working directory, independent from your classpath.